# array_key_exists Not working on simple array

Tags: php, arrays

HI I hope you can help me with my problem.
I have this array $j (for testing purposes) setup.

```
Array 
(
    [ssssjgjhs2sss] => http://diepresse.com/rss/MeinGeld
)
```

I want to add other data, but it first must be checked if the key already exists in the array so i use:

```
$nArr[$name] = $url;
$j = (array)json_decode($result[0]->privateFeeds);
if(array_key_exists($name,$j)){
    $j = array_merge((array)$j,$nArr); 
    echo "added";
}
else{
    echo "Allready_in_array";
}
```

When I add something new, i allways come to the else. Also:

```
print_r(array_key_exists($name,$j));
```

Does return nothing.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is `$arr` doing there? What does `$name` contain? What does `$result[0]->privateFeeds` contain? Did you bother checking that they actually contain what you think they contain?

Comment: I deleted $arr , forgot it. $name contains a string from a $_POST["name"] and $result[0]->privateFeeds contains this json {"ssssjgjhs2sss":"http:\/\/diepresse.com\/rss\/MeinGeld"} @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: I don't think those type casting are necessary, but you can just add second parameter of `json_decode()` as true

Comment: Simon, if you learn how to reduce your problem to a bare minimum, and keep track of your data (difficult with names like "ssssjgjhs2sss" or uncertain network retrieved data) not only you will be able to ask better questions but you also will likely solve them easily by yourself! :)

Comment: I found the error, i forgot the ! before  array_key_exists that took hours

Comment: That will just invert the test and if you never got it to true, now you will never get it to false. As @SverriM.Olsen said, did you check if `$name` does contain what you expect?

Comment: Firstly, you can decode from JSON to an associative array as follows: `json_decode($json, true)` so there's no need for the cast that you are performing: `$j = (array)json_decode($result[0]->privateFeeds);`. Secondly, when you encode/decode JSON, it's good practice to check if it was successful or not before performing any further operations - have a look at [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: @sidyll yes that was the problem why it didn't work and. However, i have rewritten almost any codepart today.

Comment: @DarraghEnright Learned did knew that, nice feature. Why can there be any errors? What errors?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it Simple :p

```
<?php  
$ar["ssssjgjhs2sss"] ="http://diepresse.com/rss/MeinGeld";
$name = "name";
$url="http://www.host.ext";

if(array_key_exists($name,$ar)){
  echo "this key is already in the array";
}
else
{
  echo " added ";
  $ar[$name]=$url;
}
?>
```